# Dart / Flutter ¿Hay alguna manera de reducir este codigo?

Tags: flutter, dart, diseño-de-clases

Estoy haciendo clases para darle variables pero pienso que repito demasiado el código, conocen alguna manera de escribir esto y que haga exactamente lo mismo.

```
 class Usuario {
  String nombreCompletoUsuario;
  String nombreUsuario;
  String apellidoPaternoUsuario;
  String apellidoMaternoUsuario;
  String correoUsuario;
  String curpUsuario;
Usuario({
  String nombreCompletoUsuario,
  String nombreUsuario,
  String apellidoPaternoUsuario,
  String apellidoMaternoUsuario,
  String correoUsuario,
  String curpUsuario
}) {
  this.nombreCompletoUsuario = nombreCompletoUsuario;
  this.nombreUsuario = nombreUsuario;
  this.apellidoPaternoUsuario = apellidoPaternoUsuario;
  this.apellidoMaternoUsuario = apellidoMaternoUsuario;
  this.correoUsuario = correoUsuario;
  this.curpUsuario = curpUsuario;
   }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo puedes hacer definiéndolos directamente en el constructor:

```dart
 class Usuario {
  final String nombreCompletoUsuario;
  final String nombreUsuario;
  final String apellidoPaternoUsuario;
  final String apellidoMaternoUsuario;
  final String correoUsuario;
  final String curpUsuario;
Usuario({
  this.nombreCompletoUsuario,
  this.nombreUsuario,
  this.apellidoPaternoUsuario,
  this.apellidoMaternoUsuario,
  this.correoUsuario,
  this.curpUsuario
});

}
```